# Bootstrap CSS for Carousel controls

Tags: html, css, carousel, bootstrap-carousel

Right so I need some help from CSS experts who can tell me what I'm looking at because I'm very new at this and I've been straying through the CSS forest without a map.

I have a website with a number of modals. Each modal has a carousel of images.

The images have some unwanted empty space around them. This empty space is part of the class="carousel-inner" div. I noticed the size of that div was 720 by 480 pixels and my images were smaller. So the first thing I did was resize the images in photoshop. That removed the empty space on the sides, but not below.

Then I tried controlling the size of the carousel-inner div by adding some CSS of my own. That largely went nowhere, and really messed up the responsiveness of the whole modal.

So I assume there is something in the CSS code relating to the carousel that is doing this. Unfortunately, there's so much of it that I really don't know what to change. I've fiddled around with some of it, but that either had no effect, or it messed stuff up.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. I've been googling and fiddling with this stuff for hours..!

So here's the code:

```css
  .carousel {
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-inner>.item {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
  -o-transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
  transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
}

.carousel-inner>.item>img,
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img {
  line-height: 1;
}

@media all and (transform-3d),
(-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .carousel-inner>.item {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;
  }
  .carousel-inner>.item.next,
  .carousel-inner>.item.active.right {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
  .carousel-inner>.item.prev,
  .carousel-inner>.item.active.left {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
  .carousel-inner>.item.next.left,
  .carousel-inner>.item.prev.right,
  .carousel-inner>.item.active {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

.carousel-inner>.active,
.carousel-inner>.next,
.carousel-inner>.prev {
  display: block;
}

.carousel-inner>.active {
  left: 0;
}

.carousel-inner>.next,
.carousel-inner>.prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner>.next {
  left: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner>.prev {
  left: -100%;
}

.carousel-inner>.next.left,
.carousel-inner>.prev.right {
  left: 0;
}

.carousel-inner>.active.left {
  left: -100%;
}

.carousel-inner>.active.right {
  left: 100%;
}

.carousel-control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 15%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  opacity: .5;
}

.carousel-control.left {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001)));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#80000000', endColorstr='#00000000', GradientType=1);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.carousel-control.right {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#80000000', GradientType=1);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.carousel-control:hover,
.carousel-control:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  outline: 0;
  opacity: .9;
}

.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .icon-next,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 5;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.carousel-control .icon-next,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .icon-next {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  font-family: serif;
  line-height: 1;
}

.carousel-control .icon-prev:before {
  content: '\2039';
}

.carousel-control .icon-next:before {
  content: '\203a';
}

.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 15;
  width: 60%;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: -30%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #000 \9;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15%;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 15%;
  z-index: 10;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

.carousel-caption .btn {
  text-shadow: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
  .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right,
  .carousel-control .icon-prev,
  .carousel-control .icon-next {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
  .carousel-control .icon-prev {
    margin-left: -10px;
  }
  .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right,
  .carousel-control .icon-next {
    margin-right: -10px;
  }
  .carousel-caption {
    right: 20%;
    left: 20%;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .carousel-indicators {
    bottom: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<!-- Portfolio Modal 1 -->
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
        <div class="lr">
          <div class="rl">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <!-- Project Details Go Here -->
              <h2>Dissonance</h2>
              <p class="item-intro text-muted">Kourse Theater, 2016</p>
              <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active" </li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" </li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" </li>
                </ol>
                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="item active">
                    <img class="img-responsive img-centered" src="http://i577.photobucket.com/albums/ss219/presmo/dissonanceCarousel0.jpg" alt="DiPreview0">
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <img class="http://i577.photobucket.com/albums/ss219/presmo/dissonanceCarousel1.jpg" alt="DiPreview1">
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <img class="img-responsive img-centered" src="http://i577.photobucket.com/albums/ss219/presmo/dissonanceCarousel2.jpg" alt="DiPreview2">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Left and right controls start : When I remove this block, the problem disappears -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                </a>
                <!-- Left and right controls end : When I remove this block, the problem disappears -->
              </div>
              <p>Some text</p>
              <p>some text</p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close Project</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And an image to show you what I mean:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkYCs.png)

Comment: "<img class="img-responsive img-centered" src="img/portfolio/diCarousel0.jpg" alt="DiPreview0 style="height:100%""> "
                should resolve

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that failed to solve the problem... :(

Comment: your snippet is not working, i can't check, make it work put images over there

Comment: Apologies, I added the images. I didn't include the entire Bootstrap CSS code because that would be unwieldy so it doesn't look 100% like my page. But there is still some extra space beneath the image.

Comment: This is not probably not precisely reproducible without the bootstrap CSS added to it; however `display:block` for the images would be the usual fix for such problems (https://www.google.com/search?q=space+under+image); although I'd assume that bootstrap would apply that itself, assuming the correct classes were used.